# Problemas com o mod_rewrite

Tags: php, htaccess

Estou tendo um problema com o mod_rewrite no .htaccess.

O problema é o seguinte: Se eu pesquiso algo como **Michael Jackson** fica assim: site.com/pesquisar/**Michael%20Jackson**/82920rdn#ir tudo vai normal.

Mas se eu pesquisar **Michael Jackson *100%* original** da o seguinte erro abaixo por causa do **%** (porcentagem). Fiz umas pesquisas e vi que o erro é nas URL amigável, mas não achei solução.

Erro:

> Bad Request
>
> Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
> Additionally, a 400 Bad Request error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Meu código no .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^pesquisar/([^/]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ /index.php?action=pesquisar&busca=$1&token=$2 [L]
 </IfModule>
```

Alguma solução para isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conseguir resolver!

A solução é converter o **%** via **urlencode**.

Exemplo: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.urlencode.php